# Page break in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

In PL/SQL program i have used

```
set pagesize 40;
```

so according to the above line the page break happens after 40 lines.

How do I increment a variable when the page break happens.
i.e. i have a variable l_page_number and I should increment the `l_page_number` by 1 whenever page break happens. How to acheieve that??

plz help me out...

Comment: PL/SQL is a procedural language, not a display language. It doesn't have page breaks. What are you displaying that needs to be paginated, and how are you doing it?

Answer (score 4):

`pagesize` is a SQL*Plus command.  In SQL*Plus we can show the page number (which I presume is what you really want) using `SQL.PNO`

The SQL*Plus documentation is online.  You can find out more about formatting [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm).

Comment: is there any way to set a manual page break in PL/SQL??? i increment a variable say l_count and i need first page break after 10 lines and a second page break after 20 lines.